# Chef - GET response of http_request in a file

Tags: chef-infra, httpresponse, chef-recipe

I am doing an http_request call GET to get the response from server. I need to store the value in a file for further use. The recipe which i have written is as follows:

```
http_request 'ha' do
  action :get
  headers = {
      'user-principal' => '{"userName":"user","password":"pass"}',
      'Accept' => 'application/json',
      'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
  }
  url 'https://node.in.company.net:2381/'
end

template '/etc/new' do
  owner "root"
  group "root"
  mode "0644"
  source "new.erb"
  variables({
    my_id:Chef::HTTP.new('https://node.in.company.net:2381/').get('/')
  })
end
```

I have used this reference: https://coderanger.net/chef-tips/#4
.

It is just creating empty file /etc/new. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to pass the headers in get and get rid of the http_request resource as it doesn't server any purpose here as far as I can tell). I.e: `.get('/',{
      'user-principal' => '{"userName":"user","password":"pass"}',
      'Accept' => 'application/json',
      'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
  })`

Comment: Yes. I was able to do it with template resource and Chef::http library. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the output from `http_request` or any other resource as resources do not have output values.

Comment: I have got rid of http_request block. This ismy current recipe. It still creates blank file app.conf . Do I need to modify the file "/templates/default/app.conf.erb" file? 
`template '/etc/app.conf' do
  variables({
    my_id: Chef::HTTP.new('https://node.in.company.net:2381/').get('/',{ 'user-principal' => '{"userName":"user","password":"pass"}', 'Accept' => 'application/json', 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' })
  })
end
`

Comment: Got it done with modifying "/templates/default/app.conf.erb" . Thanks for the help.